# Installing apps in my user directory

Tags: permissions, root

I am new to Ubuntu and I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The OS is cool. But the problem I've faced so far is with user permission. I cannot edit anything successfully; it's always telling me error here, error there. I am thinking maybe because I have installed everything in the `~/` directory. But can I use the `/home/user` directory? I mean how can I install the necessary apps in my own user directory. Like apache, mysql, php and others? will it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is a multi-user system so it generally installs software in a way to make it available to all users.

On the other hand everything that might affect other users can't be changed by an unprivileged user.

Fortunately you can privilege yourself (if you are the "first" user created during installation) by putting a `sudo` before any command which needs root permission. Thus you may change everything - but pay attention, the system will not prevent you from doing harmful things e.g. removing essential system files.

If you install software "manually" (as opposed to using apt-get), you may choose in the configuration where to install it, but I wouldn't recommend this for beginners.

BTW: ~/ is just an abbrevation for your user directory.